# IE9 FileReference.browse() shows non-modal dialogue when shows within a new window

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I would really appreciate if you can help me to this issue in Flash 4.0 FileReference.browse() dialouge.

The situation is like this.

1. open web page(contains flex button) in new window using javascript window.open() method.
2. web page in new window contains  flex button (on click event,  FileReference.browse() is called)
3. click flex button, FileDialog shows up
4. click window, FileDialog is covered by window.(That means FileDialog is not modal.)

This issue happens in IE9 only.. previous versions of IE and other browsers (Chome, FF, Safari) it works perfectly.

Any solutions or workaround to get rid of this issue?

Thanks in advance,
Sherin